# Flutter Not Waiting for Await Calls Before Moving to Next Statements with Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm an avid Flutter programmer and I'm making an app for robotics teams to communicate. The issue we're having is with the order of our methods running. We first update Firestore data, then read it again, then we build widgets based on that data. Since these all need await, we use .then and complete the next steps in them.

Here's the code showing .then and using our Firestore methods for updating and retrieving data.

```
Future<void> handleNewRequest(String currentRequest, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) async {
    FirestoreData firestoreData = new FirestoreData();
    Request newRequest = new Request(teamName, currentRequest);

    // Send new Request to Firebase
    firestoreData.makeNewUserRequestFirebase(newRequest, snapshot, widget.name).then((_) {
      return firestoreData.updateRequests(snapshot, "Ink and Metal").then((data) {
        var currentRequestData = data[0];
        return currentRequestData;
      }).then((currentRequestData) {
        setState(() {
          requestsWidgetList = generateRequestsWidget(currentRequestData);
        });
      }).then((_) {
        print("Finished with handleNewRequest");
      });
    });
  }
```

We use .then, but the order of the methods are still not right. The output with print statements:

```
I/flutter (13526): Running 'Make Request' set state
I/flutter (13526): 
I/flutter (13526): After handleNewRequest
I/flutter (13526): [{data: [Ink and Metal, r1, ]}, {data: [Ink and Metal, r2, ]}, {data: [Ink and Metal, r1, ]}]
I/flutter (13526): Finished with handleNewRequest
```

The expected order is:

```
I/flutter (13526): Running 'Make Request' set state
I/flutter (13526): 
I/flutter (13526): [{data: [Ink and Metal, r1, ]}, {data: [Ink and Metal, r2, ]}, {data: [Ink and Metal, r1, ]}]
I/flutter (13526): Finished with handleNewRequest
I/flutter (13526): After handleNewRequest
```

As can be seen, 'After handleNewRequest' should be printed last, but it is printed second.

Does anyone know any solution to wait until these lines of code are run before running the next line again?

Comment: "Since these all need await, we use .then and complete the next steps in them." That doesn't make sense.  Just use `await` throughout; it's far more straightforward.

Comment: You don't show where "After handleNewRequest" comes from, but I'm presuming it's printed by the caller of `handleNewRequest`.  Your `handleNewRequest` function neglects to explicitly return a `Future`, so the caller will not be able to wait for it to complete.  Implementing `handleNewRequest` with `await` would avoid that problem.